# Updating the prior, conditional probability (Bayes) problem

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian, conditional-probability

I've been trying to understand very hard this exercise, but I haven't been able to understand how it's solved. The topic is Bayes's theorem. This is the same exercise stated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/392912/conditional-probability-on-disease) but that question doesn't have an answer and I went a bit forward. The exercise says:

> A woman lives in a country where only 1 out of 1000 people has the
> virus. There is a test available that gives a positive result 5% of
> the time when the patient does not have Zika and a negative result 1%
> of the time when the patient does have Zika. Otherwise, it gives
> correct results.

**The questions are:**

1. What's the woman's chance of having the virus, conditional on a positive test?
2. Let the conditional probability computed in (1) serve as the new prior. Compute the new probability that she has the virus (new posterior) based on her receiving a second positive test.
3. How many consecutive positive test results would she have to receive in total (including the two previous test results) in order to be at least 95% sure that she has the virus?

**Solving the problem**

We have that:

\begin{equation}
P(Z)=0.001 \\
P(+|Z^{c})=0.05 \implies P(-|Z^{c})=0.95 \small\text{  positive and negative test given that doesn't have the virus} \\
P(-|Z)=0.01 \implies P(+|Z)=0.99 \small\text{  negative and positive test given that does have the virus}  \\
P(A|B)= \frac{P(B|A)*P(A)}{P(B|A)*P(A) + P(B|A^{c})*P(A^{c})} \small\text{by Bayes theorem}\\
\end{equation}

**For problem 1** (which is right!)
\begin{equation}
P(Z|+)=\frac{P(+|Z)*P(Z)}{P(+|Z)*P(Z)+P(+|Z^{c})*P(Z^{c})}=\frac{0.99*0.001}{0.99*0.001+0.05*0.999}=0.019
\end{equation}

Problem 2 and 3 I haven't been able to solve them accordingly. The **solution for problem 2** is:

[image]

**The solution for problem 3**:

[image]

**My questions**

- A. I understand how the first problem is solved, but I haven't found
  where that equation from Bayes Theorem comes from. I haven't even
  found a name for that equation to search in google, as when I look
  for Bayes theorem or conditional Bayes, always shows the typical
  Bayes equation. So, **where does that Bayes equation comes from?**
- B. I understand that problems 2 and 3 are solved by updating the
  prior. But how is that procedure? I tried looking it up but the
  number $0.981$ from solution 2 comes from nowhere (As I see it). So,
  **what's the procedure which I should iterate in order to answer question 2 and 3?**

Comment: A hint: Search for "law of total probability" and try if you can use that law to transform the denominator in the "typical Bayes equation", as you call it, in a way that will turn it into the equation that was given to you

Comment: Another hint: 0.981 = 1-0.019